# Set Topology: E', set of limit points of E, is closed

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Baby Rudin's Topology section, 3rd edition, page 43, problem 6.

Let $E \subset X$, metric space, $E'$ the set of limiting points of $E.$

Show that $E'$ is closed.

Second attempt:

Show that $(E')^c$ is open, let $y\in (E')^c$,

1)$y\not \in E.$

Since $y \not \in E'$, i.e. there is

a $N_r(y)\cap E=\emptyset$, $r>0.$

Assume there is a $p\in E'$ s.t.

$p\in N_r(y).$

Since $N_r(y)$ is open there is

a  $s>0$ s.t.

$N_s(p)\subset N_r(y).$

Since $p$ is a limit point,

there is a $e\in E$ with

$e\in N_s(p) \subset N_r(y)$
, a contradiction.

2)$y \in E.$

There is a $N_r(y)\cap E=${$y$}, $r>0.$

Assume there is a $p\in E'$ s.t.

$p \in N_r(y).$

Since $N_r(y)$ is open there is a $S>0$ s. t.

$N_S(p) \subset N_r(y).$

Choose $n$, pos. integer:

$s:=S/n <d(p, y). $

There is  an $e \in E$ with

$e \in N_s(p) \subset N_r(y)$, a contradiction since

$N_r(y) \cap E=${$y$}.

It follows that $(E')^c$ is open, qed.

Is this ok? Thank you.

Cf.  Henno Brandsma's answer.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the antepenultimate line. It should be $e \in N_s(p) \subset N_r(y)$.

Comment: Thanks, got it. Otherwise ok?

Comment: I think the proof is correct. If you wanted to detail everything, you would have to explain why $y \not \in E'$ implies that there exists some $r > 0$ such that $N_r(y) \cap E = \emptyset$. But that's nitpicking on my part ^^

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This follows from y not being a limit point of E.

Comment: Of course it does ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are in fact *two* cases when considering $y \notin E'$.

$y \notin E$ and in that case there is indeed $r>0$ so that $N_r(y) \cap E = \emptyset$, or

$y \in E$ and in that case there is $r>0$ so that $N_r(y) \cap E = \{y\}$ and this requires a slightly different approach.

Comment: Henno. Can I argue similarly for $y \in E$? Assume there is a $p \in N_r(y)$, have $N_s(p) \subset N_r(y)$,  with $s$ small s.t. $y \not \in N_s(p)$ and deduce a contradiction? Thank you.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Yes, $N_r(y) \subseteq (E')^\complement$: if $z \neq y$ in $N_r(y)$ find a ball $N_s(z)$ inside $N_r(y)$ that misses $y$ too and $N_s(z)$ witnesses $z \notin E'$. etc.