# Understanding Theorem 2.27(a) in Rudin

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Rudin's Theorem 2.27(a) states:

> If $X$ is a metric space and $E \subset X$, then $\overline{E}$ is closed.

I'm not sure that I fully understand Rudin's proof, and have spent some time trying to fill in the details. Here is my best attempt.

> Fix $p \in X$ with $p \not \in \overline{E} = E \cup E'$, i.e., $p$ is neither a point nor a limit point of $E$. So there exists an $r > 0$ such that $N_r (p) \cap E = \emptyset$. But since neighborhoods are open by Theorem 2.19, given $q \in N_r (p)$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $N_{\delta} (q) \subset N_r (p)$, so $N_{\delta} (q) \cap E = \emptyset$, so $q$ is not a limit point of $E$, and we have $N_r (p) \cap E' = \emptyset$. Therefore, we have
> \begin{align*}
> N_r (p) \cap \overline{E} = N_r (p) \cap \left(E \cup E'\right) = \left(N_r (p) \cap E\right) \cup \left(N_r (p) \cap E'\right) = \emptyset \cup \emptyset = \emptyset. 
> \end{align*}
> Therefore, we have $N_r (p) \subset \left(\overline{E}\right)^c$. As $p \in \left(\overline{E}\right)^c$ was arbitrary, we have that every such $p$ is an interior point and therefore $\left(\overline{E}\right)^c$ is open. By Theorem 2.23, its complement $\overline{E}$ is therefore closed.

How does this look?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Perhaps of inteerest. Rudin, same section, a problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130623/set-topology-e-set-of-limit-points-of-e-is-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the proof is correct. I would suggest only one thing: recall also in Rudin’s statement the definition in your post of $\overline{E}$. I’m writing this since sometimes $\overline{E}$ means the closure of $E$ in the sense of the intersection of all closed sets that contain $E$. By general topology this is trivially closed, hence I suggest that you explicitly write you defined $\overline{E}$ as the union of $E$ and its limit points.

Just a small remark on what you (correctly) did: note how important is the fact that $p$ is arbitrary, allowing you to conclude the proof for any point.